# Unable to use kafka mirror maker due to No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config

Tags: apache-kafka

Below are my files:

consumer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=some-id.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.username=<username>
sasl.password=<password>
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<username>" password="<password>";
```

producer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=my.kafka.broker:9092
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafka" password="<password>";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

I try to run this command:

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config consumer.properties --producer.config producer.properties --whitelist my.test.topic
```

And get this error:

```
WARNING: The default partition assignment strategy of the mirror maker will change from 'range' to 'roundrobin' in an upcoming release (so that better load balancing can be achieved). If you prefer to make this switch in advance of that release add the following to the corresponding config: 'partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor'
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder (file:/opt/kafka/libs/kafka-clients-2.2.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2021-04-13 23:01:47,172] ERROR Exception when starting mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:811)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:659)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:639)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.$anonfun$createConsumers$1(MirrorMaker.scala:114)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.$anonfun$createConsumers$1$adapted(MirrorMaker.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.createConsumers(MirrorMaker.scala:112)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerOptions.checkArgs(MirrorMaker.scala:557)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:90)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:726)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.getServiceName(KerberosLogin.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.configure(KerberosLogin.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:149)
    ... 17 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:97)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
```

I do define `sasl.jaas.config` though, so why am I getting the error about "No serviceName defined"?